# Apache Commons Ftp file uploaded 0 bytes

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I'm developing an application that needs to upload something to an FTP.
I've been unable to make apache commons works with file upload. The file uploaded has 0 bytes. I've tryed ASCII and binary mode with the same results.
Here is my code

```
    Log.d("FTP", "Connecting");
    ftpsClient.connect(server,port);


    if(ftpsClient.isConnected())
    {
        Log.d("FTP", "Sending File");
        ftpsClient.login("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");
        ftpsClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("sdcard/log.txt");
        ftpsClient.storeFile("log.txt", is);
        is.close();
        ftpsClient.logout();
        ftpsClient.disconnect();
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you try and upload a file to that server with a "real" FTP client (for instance, `lftp` on Linux)?

Comment: File is uploaded without a problem. I'm using godaddy ftp server so I doubt there is a problem with it.

Comment: Try and debug the connection, in particular pay attention to the `PASV` command and its response: is the socket address sent back to the server a "real" IP address or an RFC 1918 address?

Comment: How can I debug the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been there, done that, saw the exact same problem.

After

```
ftpsClient.login("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");
```

add

```
ftpsClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

And to expand on the answer a little bit, here's a complete snippet with progress:

```
private class FTPUploadTask extends AsyncTask<AFileDescriptor, Long, Boolean> {

    private static final int bufferSize = 64;
    private boolean isCanceling = false;
    private long fileSize = 0;

    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog( ThisActivity.this );
        pd.setCancelable( false );
        pd.setMessage( "Uploading something..." );
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setProgress(0);
        pd.setMax(100);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        pd.setProgress( (int)( progress[0] * 100 / fileSize ) );
     }

    private int storeFile( OutputStream out, String local ) {
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream( local );

            byte[] buffer = new byte[ bufferSize * 1024 ];
            int read;
            int allRead = 0;
            while( ( ( read = in.read( buffer ) ) != - 1 ) && !isCanceling ) {
                allRead += read;
                this.publishProgress( (long) allRead );
                out.write( buffer, 0, read );
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
            return allRead;
        } catch( Throwable th ) {
            Log.d( "Error: ", th.getMessage() );
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground( AFileDescriptor... params ) {
        ASubFileDescriptor file = params[0].getDefaultFile();
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftp.connect( FTPHostName );
            ftp.login( FTPUser, FTPPass );
            ftp.cwd( FTPTargetFolder );

            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                            String storeName = file.getStoreName();
            ftp.setFileType( FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE );
            this.fileSize =  file.getFile().length();
            OutputStream out = ftp.storeFileStream( storeName );
            int bytes = storeFile( out,
                       file.getFile().getAbsolutePath() );

            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
            return bytes > 0;
        } catch( Throwable th ) {
            Log.d( "FTP Error:", th.getMessage() );
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( Boolean success ) {
        try {
            pd.dismiss();
        } catch( Throwable th ) {

        }

        if( success ) {
                        // do something
        } else {
                        // do something else
    }
}
```

This snippet is used to upload certain debug information to a local server for level-2 support. Depending on how you use your upload, you may have to add more error-checking/recovery and user-interaction.

Comment: Quite welcome. I was just adding the entire bit, in case you need to add upload progress and such.